# Asterisk: Connect attempt from '192.168.x.xxx' unable to authenticate

Tags: c#, rest, curl, asterisk

Trying to connect to Asterisk 13.4.0 on Ubuntu virtual box from my .NET application: [AsterNET.ARI](https://github.com/skrusty/AsterNET.ARI) > [Conference Sample](https://github.com/skrusty/AsterNET.ARI/blob/master/Samples/SimpleConfExample/Program.cs) using the below configurations:

ari.conf

```
[general]
enabled = yes
pretty = yes
[asterisk]
type = user
read_only = no
password = asterisk
```

extensions.conf

```
[default]
exten = 1000,1,Noop()
same = n,Answer()
same = n,Stasis(simpleconf,test)
same = n,Hangup()
```

manager.conf

```
[general]
enabled = yes
webenabled = yes
port = 5038
bindaddr = 0.0.0.0
```

AsterNET.ARI.SimpleConfExample

```
public class AppConfig
    {
        public const string AppName =      "simpleconf";
        public const string RestAddress =  "http://localhost:8088/";
        public const string ServerIP =     "192.168.x.xx";
        public const int    Port =          5038;
        public const string UserName =     "asterisk";
        public const string UserPassword = "asterisk";
        public const string ConfName =     "test";
    }

private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            // Create a message client to receive events on
            Client = new AriClient(new StasisEndpoint(AppConfig.ServerIP, AppConfig.Port, AppConfig.UserName, AppConfig.UserPassword), AppConfig.AppName);
            Conference.Conferences.Add(new Conference(Client, Guid.NewGuid(), AppConfig.ConferenceName));
            ....
        }
```

And I get the below from the CLI terminal:

`Connect attempt from '192.168.x.xxx' unable to authenticate`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The Asterisk Manager Interface (AMI) and the Asterisk REST Interface (ARI) are two different animals. Your code is mixing and matching various things from both, specifically the port to connect on - 5038 is the AMI port, not the ARI one. Change your `Port` declaration to:

```
public const int    Port =          8088;
```

Comment: changed the port to 8088, the console app says: `Loaded... waiting for connections`, and nothing happens...

Comment: Sorry, I don't know anything about ARI other than that you were using the wrong port.

Comment: your manager.conf port is 5038...perhaps change that as well?